# How do I get my GPU to start running in blender?

Tags: rendering

I have a graphics card and when I'm in blender, it does not show up as running. I switched the render to GPU, but it gets greyed out and still uses my CPU. Im wondering how to make it so the render uses my GPU instead of my CPU.

Comment: What kind of GPU do you have? Some are not compatible with GPU render.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit>Preferences>System The at the top of the window you should see cycles render devices. Select CUDA and then check the devices you would like blender to use.